# Laravel: fetch pivot relationship through another relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database, eloquent

Using Laravel, I'd like to fetch an order status (`order_status` table) from an order (`orders` table) based on the
locale relationship stored in the `orders` table using a pivot table (`order_status_locale` table).
The pivot table contains the "localised" order status from the order.

Of course, I could fetch the localised order status (`order_status_locale`) directly from the database, but I'd like to
fetch the localised order status through a Laravel relationship.

Something like this:

```php
$order = Order::find(123);
$order->localisedOrderStatus->label;
```

This is an example of the database structure:

```
orders:
    id: int
    locale_id: int
    ...other columns

locales:
    id: int
    ...other columns

order_statuses:
    id: int
    ...other columns

order_status_locale:
    order_status_id: int
    locale_id: int
    label: varchar
```

Answer (score 0):

its sometimes better to make model of your pivot table. like **OrderStatusLocale.php**

then you can make the relation through it.

lastly if you want to achieve

```
$order->localisedOrderStatus->label;
```

you can use laravel has one through. or i think its better to go through the relation like `$order->order_status->locale->label`

Comment: Thanks but that's not the expected solution. I need to fetch a localised order status based on the locale on the order. The relationships are: `order belongsTo locale` `order belongsTo orderStatus` `orderStatus belongsToMany locale`. I need the `order belongsToThrough.... locale` relationship to fetch the localised order status label.